# How to read or write data from a MySQL cPannel Database in Java for an Android App

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, cpanel

Any tutorials out there on how to send and received data to and from a MySQL database hosted on a server using cPannel? I'm trying to make an android app that connects to the internet, and it needs to read and write data to and from the hosted database. The database is a MySQL one and is hosted on godaddy. I've been on the internet all day today looking, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your best bet is making some sort of api call to the server (using html or some sort of common mark up xml, json etc) interacting through sql querries directly is not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to write a webservice which will get the data from your mysql database and send it to your android app.

**First** of all you need a server which you have already. Create space to write php scripts there to interact withe the database that is hosted there.

**Second** Write a php script on your server which can retrieve the required data from the MySQL database. Encode the retrieved data inside a JSON object and send it back to your app. From your app you have to call the URL where the webservice is hosted, and the php script will do the interaction with the database, retrieve the results and send it back to your app in JSON.

**Third** - Follow the same method to send and retrieve data to server. Create multiple webservice as per your requirements.

This tutorial excellently illustrates what you are looking for. This example uses a local server. You can skip some of the steps there. Hope it helps. URL: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

If you still got any questions, comment below. I will be happy to help.

Thanks!